# Why the storage capacity limitation in laptops

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd, storage, dell-inspiron

As per the documentation for Dell Inspiron 5000 laptops, [inspiron-15-5577](http://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/inspiron-15-5577-gaming-laptop_setup%20guide_en-us.pdf), in page 15 it is mentioned that,

[Storage] Capacity [of the laptop is]

Hard drive

• Up to 1 TB (hard drive only)

• Up to 1 TB hard drive + up to 128 GB SSD

• Up to 512 GB (PCIe SSD)

Does this means,

• it is not possible to put a 2TB HDD in the laptop?

• an SSD bigger than 128 GB capacity wont work along with a 1TB HDD?

• an SSD bigger than 512 GB capacity wont work at all in this laptop?

If this is correct, why so? Is there any technical constraints?

Comment: The only technical limitation would be space.  I suspect what those numbers refer to are the largest capacities pre-configured and sold by Dell for that series.  It may also reflect the largest capacities actually tested by Dell, so they're only guaranteeing what they tested.

Comment: It depends on what the BIOS can handle. It will mean that a 2TB HDD may not function correctly or may not even boot at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the age of the laptop it may use the "old" BIOS firmware or have UEFI but in "compatibility support" mode. On these systems Windows only supports booting from MBR partitioned disks.

MBR partitioning only supports 1.7TB, so 2TB and above disks may be wasted.

On a full UEFI system Windows uses GPT partitioning where this limit does not exist.

The other limits are probably "we tested this but YMMV". I don't see why there would be a limit on the size of one disk when combined with another disk, the limits will be per disk.

Comment: Just to add to this answer, some HDD are physically thicker than others (and I noticed there are 7mm and 9mm 2.5" HDD - not sure about SSD). So the limitation could also be physical. But if you can get past the physical limitation, the rest is as per Mokubai's answer.

Comment: @Darius while there are different heights on drives, that has nothing to do with their storage capacity.

Comment: The machine is Q2-2017 model, and I can confirm that the existing (preconfigured) 128GB SSD and 1TB HDD are both using GPT. So like you and @fixer1234 commented, it'd be "we tested this but YMMV!"

Comment: @Keltari The HD height absolutely can affect its storage capacity. Just try to find a 4 TB laptop drive ("2.5 inch" form factor) in 9mm height. You can't, at least not today. But they are out there in 15mm height. The taller drive has room for a second 2 TB platter and the accompanying heads.

Answer (score 3):

### Dell specs reflect available configurations, not necessarily technical limitations

When discussing maximum capacity of hard disks, Dell documentation only acknowledges configurations  *available from and tested by Dell* for a particular system.

Because Dell tests all possible configurations it makes available for sale, it's possible that there is a technical reason a particular product model cannot support a drive larger than what Dell offers. However, this is usually not the case. To avoid an overwhelming number of options, especially with product lines targeted at the general public (e.g. Inspiron), only a limited number of drive sizes will be tested and offered. As a result, often much larger drives can be installed without trouble.

Additionally, one will notice that Dell's specifications are unnecessarily *specific*. For example, the specs you mention make no mention of support for SSHDs, but does affirm support for hard drives (a.k.a. "HD", which specifically refers to traditional spinning rust in Dell marketing) and SSDs. This isn't because this modern machine would fail to work with a hybrid hard disk, but because Dell doesn't offer them in some model lines.

FWIW, on a regular basis I successfully install hard drives much larger than those "supported" according to Dell's specifications.

You'll find the same phenomenon true with Dell's specs for graphics cards.

On the other hand, Dell specs for RAM and CPUs tends to be more true to the actual limits of the machine.